# Pandas groupby operation

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to perform a groupby operation in pandas.  For example, I want to group field B as below.
Two: anything with a 2 in front.
Three: anything with a 3 in front.
Otherwise leave the cell alone.

For example:
df

```
index   A    B    Count  Value
x       abc  1-a    1      1
x       abc  2-a    2      2
x       abc  2-b    1      4
x       xyz  3-b    2      0
x       xyz  3-a    3      2
y       abc  1-b    1      5
y       abc  1-c    0      3
y       ijk  3-a    2      1
y       ijk  2-c    1      2
```

The result would be:

```
index   A    B    Count  Value    (Count: sum by group, Value: average by group)
x       abc  1-a    1      1
x       abc  Two    2      3
x       xyz  Three  2      1
y       abc  1-b    1      5
y       abc  1-c    0      3
y       ijk  Three  2      1
y       ijk  Two    1      2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `str.split` + `agg`

```
df['B']=np.where(df['B'].str.split('-',expand=True)[0]!='1',df['B'].str.split('-',expand=True)[0],df['B'])
df.groupby(['index','A','B']).agg({'Count':'sum','Value':'mean'}).reset_index()
Out[1628]: 
  index    A    B  Count  Value
0     x  abc  1-a      1      1
1     x  abc    2      3      3
2     x  xyz    3      5      1
3     y  abc  1-b      1      5
4     y  abc  1-c      0      3
5     y  ijk    2      1      2
6     y  ijk    3      2      1
```

For your case

```
df.groupby(['index','A','B']).agg(lambda x : x.mean() if x.name.startswith('Value') else x.sum()).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks Wen! How would the code be like if I have multiple values (Values1, Value2, Value3,....) and I want to get the mean for those?  Would there be a more convenient way?

Comment: `df.groupby(['index','A','B']).agg(lambda x : x.mean() if x.name.startswith('Value') else x.sum()).reset_index()` @TylerNG

Answer (score 2):

Could also use `str.partition`:

```
# make new 'B'
df.B.where(df.B.str.contains('1'), other = df.B.str.partition('-')[0], inplace = True)

# group and agg
df.groupby([
    'index',
    'A',
    'B'
]).agg({
    'Count' : 'sum',
    'Value' : 'mean'
}).reset_index()
```

[image: group and agg]